# GPSD: Receive position updates frequency (from daemon)

Tags: gps

What is the default frequency that the GPSD can send the location information it picked up from satellite to the computer or device connected and requesting it from its daemon?

Is it as fast as it receives a fix from the satellites (1Hz, 5Hz, 10Hz etc.)? Or is there some kind of setting that can be configured?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The speed at which the `gpsd` updates is dependent on the speed of the device it is polling for location and the reception that device has with regard to the satellites.

GPS signal is very weak and works best outdoors with a clear line-of-sight with the sky. The GPS device that `gpsd` polls uses the signals from several GPS satellites to compute a location and then passes that information on to the `gpsd` daemon at a fixed rate (in some cases, once per second).

I would recommend reading the [documentation](http://catb.org/gpsd/) about `gpsd`. If performance is your biggest concern, might I suggest [a whitepaper](http://catb.org/gpsd/performance.html) analyzing the performance of `gpsd` and several GPS devices?

Comment: so you're basically saying that the frequency of how often to receive new coordinates depends on the hardware device and cannot be modified from the gpsd software to receive the information even faster..?

Comment: @bubbly Yes, that is what I am indeed saying.